# Oracle DB: Select Values from a list that do not exist in DB

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a list of values. Some of which do not exist in the DB. I'd like to find which values in the list do not exist.

Eg. Given the table:

```
id name
--------
1 John
2 Amy
3 Kevin
4 Matt
5 Mark
6 Jim
7 Angela
8 Erin
```

With a list containing:

```
John, Amy, Sarah, Sam
```

I'd like to only return:

```
Sarah, Sam
```

How can I achieve this using Oracle DB? I know I could create a new table, insert the values from my list, do a join, then drop the table. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a table on-the-fly:

```
select name from
(

  select 'John'  as name from dual union all
  select 'Amy'   as name from dual union all
  select 'Sarah' as name from dual union all
  select 'Sam'   as name from dual
) names
where name not in (select name from mytable);
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use a `left join` or `not exists`:

```
select name
from (select 'John' as name from dual union all
      select 'Amy' as name from dual union all
      select 'Sarah' as name from dual union all
      select 'Sam' as name from dual 
     ) n left join
     t
     using (name)
where t.name is null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a collection constructor, for example:

```
select column_value from soda_key_list_t('John', 'Amy', 'Sarah', 'Sam');
```

You can create your own "table of strings" collection type if you don't already have one, e.g.

```
create or replace type varchar2_tt as table of varchar2(4000);
```

or else see what existing types are available:

```
select owner, type_name, length
from   all_coll_types t
where  t.coll_type = 'TABLE'
and    t.elem_type_name = 'VARCHAR2'
order by 1,2;
```

I've used `soda_key_list_t` which is included with Oracle 18c onwards as part of the [Simple Oracle Document Access](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/simple-oracle-document-access/adsdi/overview-soda.html) feature. Others include `dbms_debug_vc2coll` and `ora_mining_varchar2_nt`.

Answer (score 0):

> You can also use a unpivot table approach :

```
      select Number as list from (    
        select * from (
           select 'jn','jimmy','ronny' from dual ) 
        unpivot
       (  
        "Values" FOR "Number" IN ("'JN'","'JIMMY'","'RONNY'")   
       )
       )
     minus
    
     select list from your_table;
```